# File timestamp not changing even with touch

Tags: centos, wget, timestamp

I have the following problem. I have a bash script that uses wget to get a few files from the build server, and then scp's them over to the production system: Here is the relevant snippet:

```
#Several of these lines
wget -nv -O birt_reports.zip "http://buildserver:8111/guestAuth/repository/download/bt6/.lastFinished/birt_reports.zip"

#files in the for loop left out for simplicity
for upload_file in "birt_reports.zip"; do

    scp -B -i /root/$keyfile  $upload_file $user@gateway:/home/$user/deploy_staging
    touch $upload_file
done
```

Even with the touch in there the time shown in ls -l of the directory is the time the file was first created. If I do the wget outside the bash script or the touch outside the bash script, the time updates correctly.

What could the issue be?

Comment: I assume the account has write permissions on the file..

Comment: Yes, it is run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Using the bellow command it is supose to set the timestamp of the file to your system current datetime:

```
touch -t `date +%y%m%d%H%M.%S` /path/to/filename
```

You could try it instead of the plain touch command alone.

Also when you run your bash script run with:

```
bash -xv your_bash_script.bash
```

also try using the full path of your commands, to verify the full path of the command do:

`whereis touch`

Since you could be using this without a shell enviroment using the full path is more recommended to make sure it will run every command without problems.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps `/bin/touch -m $upload_file` is better suited, as it changes the modification time to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file being properly scp'ed?
(I can't comment on your question post)

If not, then I think you're missing something to the uploaded file path within the for loop for both commands. Prix points out the way to check the actual commands.

Comment: Yes, oddly the file does correctly copy.